# Let $X$ be a random variable(either discrete or continuous) with $E|X|<\infty$. Show that $E|X|^p\leq\sum_{n\geq0}P(|X|^p>n)$ where $p>0$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable(either discrete or continuous) with $E|X|<\infty$. Show that $E|X|^p\leq\sum_{n\geq0}P(|X|^p>n)$ where $p>0$.

Comment: Hint: Can you show that for every nonnegative $u$, $$u\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathbf 1_{u>n},$$ apply this pointwise inequality to $|X|^p$ and integrate the result?

Comment: Alternatively, look for one of the many pages on the site already explaining this.

Comment: why is not $u\geq\sum_{n=0}I_{u>n}$?

Comment: ?? Did you try to compute the LHS and the RHS and compare them for some specific $u$?

Comment: oh I just thought $\geq$ for $n$ starts from $1$. It makes sense to me now.